# Adding thermal camera plugin to the robot description in another package

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the thermal camera in my robot. I have 3 pcks : the first package that has the launch file where I it looks from the second pkg for the robot discreption that uses the plugins or the sensor from the third packgae.

I did the following:
In package 3:
I downloaded the package hector_gazebo from this link https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo

In package 2:

I have the file1.xacro file that has all the sensors that the robot has and I added the following sensor

```
 <robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"> 

 <!-- here are all the plugins and the other sensors like the cameras, imu and the depth cameras and all other macros --> 
 <!-- thermal -->
<xacro:macro name="thermal_camera"
params="namespace parent_link camera_suffix frame_rate
  horizontal_fov image_width image_height image_format min_distance
  max_distance noise_mean noise_stddev enable_visual *geometry *origin">
<link name="${namespace}/camera_${camera_suffix}_link">
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <xacro:insert_block name="geometry" />
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <xacro:if value="${enable_visual}">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <xacro:insert_block name="geometry" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="red" />
    </visual>
  </xacro:if>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="1e-5" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
  </inertial>
</link>
<joint name="${namespace}/camera_${camera_suffix}_joint" type="fixed">
  <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
  <parent link="${parent_link}" />
  <child link="${namespace}/camera_${camera_suffix}_link" />
</joint>
<gazebo reference="${namespace}/camera_${camera_suffix}_link">
  <sensor type="camera" name="${namespace}_camera_${camera_suffix}">
    <update_rate>${frame_rate}</update_rate>
    <camera name="head">
      <horizontal_fov>${horizontal_fov}</horizontal_fov>
      <image>
        <width>${image_width}</width>
        <height>${image_height}</height>
        <format>${image_format}</format>
      </image>
      <clip>
        <near>${min_distance}</near>
        <far>${max_distance}</far>
      </clip>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
             That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
             channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
        <mean>${noise_mean}</mean>
        <stddev>${noise_stddev}</stddev>
      </noise>
    </camera>
    <plugin name="thermal_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_thermal_depth_camera.so">
      <robotNamespace>${namespace}</robotNamespace>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>${frame_rate}</updateRate>
      <cameraName>camera_${camera_suffix}</cameraName>
      <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <frameName>camera_${camera_suffix}_link</frameName>
      <hackBaseline>0.0</hackBaseline>
      <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
      <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
      <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
      <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
      <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>
```

</xacro:macro>

I run the following command:
rosrun xacro xacro.py file1.xacro
the output was the following:
<--

-->
   -->

```
</robot>
```

I edited the pkg.xml in package 2 file to be the following :

```
<package>
<name>robot_description</name>
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>hector_gazebo_thermal_camera</build_depend>
<run_depend>hector_gazebo_thermal_camera</run_depend>
</package>
```

I also modified the Cmake.list file in package 2 like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robot_description)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS hector_gazebo_thermal_camera)
catkin_package() 
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GAZEBO_CXX_FLAGS}")
include_directories(${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
## Find Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY meshes DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY urdf DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

then I added the following file2.gazebo file in package 2:

```
 <robot name="$(arg name)" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.14159265359" />

 <xacro:thermal_camera name="thermal_cam" parent="base_link" ros_topic="/thermal/camera/image" cam_info_topic="thermal/camera/camera_info" update_rate="20" res_x="640" res_y="480" image_format="R8G8B8" hfov="100"> 
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.020" rpy="0 ${M_PI/2} 0"/>
 </xacro:thermal_camera>
</robot>
```

In package 1 :
I have the launch file that spawn the robot and send to it the following parameters:

```
  <group ns="robot_1">
  <include file="$(find package_gazebo)/launch/spawn_robot.launch">
  <arg name="model" value="$(find package2)/urdf/file2.gazebo" />
  <arg name="enable_logging" value="$(arg enable_logging)" />
  <arg name="enable_ground_truth" value="$(arg enable_ground_truth)" />
  <arg name="log_file" value="$(arg log_file)"/>
  <arg name="x" value="-3.0"/>
  <arg name="y" value="-3.0"/>
  <arg name="Y" value="3.14"/> 
  <arg name="name" value="robot_1"/>
```

when I run the launch file I got the following error :

```
while processing /home/mm/catkin_ws/src/package_gazebo/launch/spawn_robot.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [package2]: command [     /opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py '/home/mm/catkin_ws/src/package2/urdf/file1.gazebo'     enable_logging:=false     enable_ground_truth:=true     log_file:=Change_Me name:=uav_1] returned with code [1]. 
Param xml is <param command="     $(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(arg model)'     enable_logging:=$(arg enable_logging)        enable_ground_truth:=$(arg enable_ground_truth)     log_file:=$(arg log_file) name:=$(arg name)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Note: package_gazebo is package 4 that depends on gazebo_plugins

how can I add the thermal plugin to my robot and what is the error in the way I did ? if my method is wrong what is the right method ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235689/adding-thermal-camera-plugin-to-the-robot-description-in-another-package/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find a comprehensive example of a robot equipped with the a simulated thermal camera here: [tracker_default.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_common/blob/master/hector_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_default.urdf.xacro#L179).

There, the [flir_a35_camera](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models/blob/indigo-devel/hector_sensors_description/urdf/flir_a35_camera.urdf.xacro) macro is used.

You can install a complete working workspace with which allows spawning the robot in Gazebo as described in [hector_tracker_install](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_install).

From this example you should be able to look up everything you're interested in. It looks like the error you're getting is related to your launch file setup, possibly in your `spawn_robot.launch` file.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2016-06-04**:
Thank you it worked with me. I downloaded the package and added the required tags from the  tracker_default.urdf.xacro file and it worked.